# Css3 webkit invalid property value for width

Tags: css

I want a div to have a specific width in IE and a different width to be applied in Chrome.

```
#welcome {
  width: 200px; //1. style for IE
  width: -webkit-300px; //2. style for chrome
}​
```

The point '2' is showing an "invalid property value" when I inspect in chrome. Is webkit not supported for the property 'width'? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: That's not how vendor prefixes work, or what they are meant for.

Comment: Different widths in different browsers??...perhaps you just need a good `reset.css` or use something like [**Normlize**](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that fixed the issue was to use 'calc' function and supply a default value

```
#welcome {
  width: 200px; //1. style for IE
  width: -webkit-calc(300px); //2. style for chrome - WORKS
}​
```

The interesting take-away was to learn that ['calc' method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) can work with single argument also.

Comment: If by Chrome you mean "all browsers that implement `-webkit-calc()`", then this will work for sure. But this is a horrible hack and I hope nobody uses it in production.

Answer (score 0):

There is no secure way of detecting this. Sure, -webkit-calc() works right now, but next version of Chrome might stop listening to it in favor of calc().

The best way is still 1. Make it work in both browsers with the same value. 2. Include a different IE CSS file with HTML if statements. Like this:

```
<!--[if IE ]>
  <link href="iecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Tell us what you really trying to do, maybe we can get 200px to work for you :)

Comment: Except that IE10 and up don't recognize conditional statements.

Comment: OMG, I didn't know that. Seems to be true... wtf. I never had to use this for IE10, so I guess they are kind of right, but IE10 still has some funny things going on.

Comment: #2 also depends on whether the browser with the problem behavior is IE or Chrome. It's not clear from the question, since no other browsers are mentioned, and as you've stated in your comment there isn't even a problem statement to begin with.